# jQuery to send additional data along with database columns?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I am using jQuery datatable serverside. I want to return some extra info with database columns like csrf token, hidden fields and form on each row.

```
//define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 =>'id',
        1 =>'date',
        2 =>'applicant_name', 
        3 => 'ldate',
        4 => 'age',
        5 => 'address'
        );
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please provide a sample datatable, database, ... and desired output.  Then what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This example shows you how to send additional parameters to the server side along with the request. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

from example

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
                // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                // etc
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option would just be to use the object data source then you can send back any extra keys you want and just map the row data you need to show to your columns - Full docs here https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html